# Why does TypeScript infer this type for the array item with a union of array types?

Tags: typescript

I'm having trouble understanding why TypeScript is inferring a certain type for an array element when the type is a union type and the types 'overlap'. I've reduced it to this minimum repro:

```
interface Base {
    id: string;
}

interface Child {
    id: string;
    parentId: string;
}

interface Obj {
    nodes1: Base[] | Child[];
    nodes2: (Base | Child)[];
}

const obj: Obj = {
    nodes1: [],
    nodes2: []
};

const node1 = obj.nodes1[0]; // typed as Base
const node2 = obj.nodes2[0]; // typed as Base | Child
```

If I change `Base` so it isn't just a subset of `Child` properties like this:

```
interface Base {
    baseId: string;
}
```

Now, both `node1` and `node2` are inferred as `Base | Child`. This is what I'd expected the first time. In my real code, the array can either be all of type `Base` or all of type `Child` so the typing feels better as `Base[] | Child[]` but I've had to go with `(Base | Child)[]` for now. I could do a larger refactor to introduce generics but it's not a simple change.

Why is the type inferred as `Base` only and not `Base | Child`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [microsoft/TypeScript#43667](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43667) for a canonical answer.  This is a design limitation of TypeScript.

As you might be aware: in TypeScript's [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) type system, `Child` is a subtype of `Base` even though it is not explicitly declared as such.  So every value of type `Child` is *also* a value of type `Base` (although not vice-versa).  That means `Child | Base` is equivalent to `Base`... although the compiler is not always aggressive about *reducing* the former to the latter.  (Compare this to the behavior with something like `"foo" | string`, which is always immediately reduced to `string` by the compiler.)

Subtype reduction is often desirable, but there are some places where `Child | Base`'s behavior is observably different from `Base`'s, such as [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks), IntelliSense hinting, or the sort of unsound type guarding that happens [with the `in` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#type-guards-inferred-from-in-operator).  You haven't shown why it matters to you that you are getting a `Base` as opposed to a `Child | Base`, but presumably it's one of these observable differences or something like it.

---

My advice here is first to think carefully about whether or not you really need this distinction.  If so, then you might consider preventing `Base` from being a subtype of `Child`, possibly by adding an optional property to it:

```
interface Base {
    id: string;
    __baseMarker?: never; // <-- added property
}
```

So now we're saying that a `Base` has a `string`-valued `id` and either no `__baseMarker` property, or one with a value of type `never` (which is impossible).  So it's basically "there is no `__baseMarker` property" (well, it could be `undefined`).  This isn't much different from your original definition, but now  `Child extends Base` is false and `Child | Base` is not equivalent to `Base`:

```
const node1 = obj.nodes1[0]; // typed as Base | Child
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN4ChkHLAAmAXMhmFKAOYDc+hA+kwEaYQCycUA1tAH5yICADdoDAL65coSLEQoAwgAtgAG2LI8hImQpVaDXQAceEcAEl9laiHq5ps8NHhJkAeVYArbYwIgAPbEEBgAjOToWADaALrIAD7IqhrEccaEQSEYAEzkABRRKEkpmgCU6Y4yCIEglMiBPuRevgC8frpZoRHIcQA0-shdueRxjgy4NXVgQ8EQYcjtjd4AdMNh0QAMsXTIAPR7yGAAniYQWphoHInJapqTtfVdOYsNPmtzuVs7+4cnZxcMFcsDdSsQgA)

Comment: Thank you, great answer. I did a search on GH (and SO) but hadn't found the answer. The code branches later and uses something on `Child` (if it is a `Child`). Because TS thinks it will never be `Child`, it infers the type as `never` after the check and so results in an error.